# Response from Purchases.Subscriptions.Get have EmailAddress, FamilyName and GivenName fields returned null

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api, in-app-subscription

Android app Akita Security in Google Play 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.highiot.mob

Application have subscription to purchase. After the user purchase it from his device, I see the purchase token of his purchase and call publisherService.Purchases.Subscriptions.Get 
to see name and email of user that purchased my subscription. 
My problem is that EmailAddress, GivenName and FamilyName fields that returned in the response to Get are null. 
Other fields like price, country etc. are OK.

Code of purchase in my app:

```
 private async void Purcase(string productId)
 {
        try
        {
            var connected = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.ConnectAsync();

            if (!connected)
            {
                //Couldn't connect to billing, could be offline, alert user
                return;
            }

            //try to purchase item
            CrossInAppBilling.Current.InTestingMode = true;
            var purchase = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.Subscription, "apppayload");
            if (purchase == null)
            {                   
                //Not purchased, alert the user
            }
            else
            {
                //Purchased, save this information
                var id = purchase.Id;
                var token = purchase.PurchaseToken;
                var state = purchase.State;
                bool status = false;
                if (state == PurchaseState.PaymentPending)
                {
                    status = true;
                }
                ViewModel.SendSubscription(productId, token, "Google", status);             
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Something bad has occurred, alert user
        }
        finally
        {
            //Disconnect, it is okay if we never connected
            await CrossInAppBilling.Current.DisconnectAsync();
        }
    }
```

Code when I call Google API Subscriptions.Get:

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool acknowledge = false;
        string projectId = "robotic-circle-243009";
        string subscriptionId = "highiot-admin-api";
        var _credentialsJson = "HighIoT_key.json";

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, _credentialsJson));

        SubscriptionName subscriptionName = new SubscriptionName(projectId, subscriptionId);
        SubscriberClient subscriber = await SubscriberClient.CreateAsync(subscriptionName);

        GoogleCredential credentialsPlay;
        using (var key = new FileStream(_credentialsJson, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        credentialsPlay = GoogleCredential.FromStream(key).CreateScoped(Scope.Androidpublisher);

        var publisherService = new AndroidPublisherService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credentialsPlay
        });

        var request1 = publisherService.Purchases.Subscriptions.Get("com.highiot.mob", "com.highiot.mob.test_subsription", "nceeeoihojjngafdmfmahbii.AO-J1Ow8yISTj4C6MW4mKgXYp9Tizo7iZ8JP6PgIRenFLHj4xHaAuCxffDL5jaxEzq_t2IopZXXa4_uLyZYBsXMwk_wn3pwMXoL9rNDWJoZV8SCkVsXcAlaMJe0l2Mn_-OhhuHbjPVP8Tn0ruP4WUlxGPyxUjkNv_Q");
        var response1 = request1.Execute();  
  }
```

Response I get in response1:

```
Name                     Value
```

◢   response1       {Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3.Data.SubscriptionPurchase}

```
AcknowledgementState       1

AutoRenewing               false

AutoResumeTimeMillis       null

CancelReason               0

▶ CancelSurveyResult    {Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3.Data.SubscriptionCancelSurveyResult}

CountryCode                “UA”

DeveloperPayload           “apppayload”

ETag    “\”kLoaNGFQwzHXpxRSLTfX9req9yE/1xXhq0Lm_lUloQUDN3UhbVIoE08\””

EmailAddress                null

ExpiryTimeMillis            1568883651389

FamilyName                  null

GivenName                   null

Kind                        “androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase”

LinkedPurchaseToken         null

OrderId                     “GPA.3309-8881-6545-64850”

PaymentState                1

PriceAmountMicros           21990000

PriceChange                 null

PriceCurrencyCode           “UAH”

ProfileId                   null

ProfileName                 null

PurchaseType                null

StartTimeMillis             1566205275451

UserCancellationTimeMillis  1566209506502
```

Credentials file HighIoT_key.json:
    {
      "type": "service_account",

```
  "project_id": "robotic-circle-243009",


  "private_key_id": "cb017791695e97d8b2ab68ae94d940ba07def824",

  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\neRHZgYsNE/U60DnuZsv4wZg=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",

  "client_email": "highiot-server@robotic-circle-243009.iam.gserviceaccount.com",

  "client_id": "110565816019675715733",

  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",

  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",

  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",

  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/highiot-server%40robotic-circle-243009.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

}

On Google Play Console: 
[I link the project to the google play console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7UuX.png)

[I add the Service account to the google play console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02rOK.png)

[It's present in the user menu of google play console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEG4Y.png)

ON GOOGLE API DEVELOPER CONSOLE

[I give him permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIwV6.png)

[In google developer console I gave permission to the service account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LToeZ.png)

[And of course I've enabled the google Play Android Developer Api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LbJu.png)

[And added scope to see user info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWrFs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the confusion, but the fields you mention are only for when users [Subscribe with Google](https://newsinitiative.withgoogle.com/subscriptions). For an exhaustive list of fields that and the conditions under which they are available, please see https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions

Comment: Hi yes I saw it, sorry I not understand how implement Subscribe with Google. When purchase happen - user ask to enter google account, and payment made from google account with connected credit card. user have gmail confirmation after he purchased. It not called Subscribe with google? What should I implement in my code to be Subscribe with google?

Comment: Subscribe with Google (https://developers.google.com/news/subscribe/) is a very particular service within Google Play Billing. If you just want to sell products or services then you should follow the general guideline. Please follow this link for more details: https://blog.google/outreach-initiatives/google-news-initiative/introducing-subscribe-google/